# Points won't move by keyboard input in OpenGl

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glut

I'm Trying to move several points (rendered horizontally) from top to bottom in OpenGl. The code runs without any error. When i try to handle events like-> Start moving, speeding up/down or stop moving it doesn't work. Below is the code.

```
#include <gl/glut.h>
int pointStatus=0;
float pointX = 0.0f;
float pointY = 0.0f;
float speed, b = 0.5;
char s;
void Point(int x1, int y1)
{
glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0); 
glPointSize(5);
glPushMatrix();

glBegin(GL_POINTS);
glVertex2i(x1, y1);
glPopMatrix();

glEnd();
}

void Draw()
{
int x=0, y=6;
for (x = 0; x <= 6; x +=  1)
    {
        Point(x,y); 
    }
glFlush();
}

void movePoint(int s, int x, int b)//
{
if (pointStatus == 1)
{
    pointY -= b + speed;
}
if (pointY>14)
{
    pointY = -6;
}
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(pointX, pointY, 0);
Draw();
glPopMatrix();
}

void handleKeypress(unsigned char key, int x, int y) 
{
if (key == '1')
{                      
    pointStatus = 1; // start
    b = +0.05;
    speed = 0.5;

}

else if (key == '=' || key == '+')
{
    pointStatus = 1;    //speed up
    b = +.05;
    speed += .2;

}
else if (key == '-' || key == '_')      
{
    pointStatus = 1; //speed down 
    b = -.05;
    speed -= .2;
}
else if (key == '2')
{
    pointStatus = 0; //stop
    speed = 0;
}
}

void myDisplay(void)
{
movePoint(s, b, speed);
//glFlush();
glutPostRedisplay();
glutSwapBuffers();
}

void Initialize() {
glClearColor(0.435294, 0.258824, 0.258824,0.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(-14.0, 14.0, -14.0, 14.0, -1.0, 10.0); // left, right, bottom, top, near and far
}

int main(int iArgc, char** cppArgv) {
glutInit(&iArgc, cppArgv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
glutInitWindowSize(700,500);
glutInitWindowPosition(400, 200);
glutCreateWindow("tuntaa");
Initialize();

glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);
glutKeyboardFunc(handleKeypress);
glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Don't call `glutPostRedisplay()` from a display callback, if you want that behavior set an idle callback via `glutIdleFunc()`.
- Don't update state from the draw function, do that in a separate pass.
- You're missing a `glClear()`.
- Reset your projection and modelvew each frame, helps prevent hard-to-diagnose errors.
- Use `GLUT_DOUBLE` if you're going to use `glutSwapBuffers()`.
- If you want an even frame-rate (in the absence of reliable vsync) set a timer callback and call `glutPostRedisplay()` (and re-arm the timer).  You can do your physics update there too.
- Bonus points: `glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME)` & [Fix your timestep!](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/)

All together:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <map>

std::map< int, bool > keys;
void special( int key, int x, int y )
{
    keys[ key ] = true;
}
void specialUp( int key, int x, int y )
{
    keys[ key ] = false;
}

float xpos = 0;
float ypos = 0;
void update()
{
    const float speed = 1.0;
    if( keys[ GLUT_KEY_LEFT ] )
    {
        xpos -= speed;
    }
    if( keys[ GLUT_KEY_RIGHT ] )
    {
        xpos += speed;
    }
    if( keys[ GLUT_KEY_UP ] )
    {
        ypos += speed;
    }
    if( keys[ GLUT_KEY_DOWN ] )
    {
        ypos -= speed;
    }
}

void display()
{
    glClearColor( 0.435294, 0.258824, 0.258824, 0.0 );
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho( -100, 100, -100, 100, -1, 1 );

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    glTranslatef( xpos, ypos, 0 );
    glScalef( 10, 10, 1 );
    glBegin( GL_QUADS );
    glVertex2i( -1, -1 );
    glVertex2i(  1, -1 );
    glVertex2i(  1,  1 );
    glVertex2i( -1,  1 );
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void timer( int value )
{
    update();
    glutTimerFunc( 16, timer, 0 );
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 640, 640 );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );

    glutSpecialFunc( special );
    glutSpecialUpFunc( specialUp );

    glutTimerFunc( 0, timer, 0 );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```